# ZoneAlarm is blocking box.net in Firefox but not in Chrome. Open ports 80 and 443?

Tags: firefox, security, firewall, port, zonealarm

This may not be the place to ask this question, as the usual suspects---ZoneAlarm, box.net, and Mozilla---have forums of their own for these kind of questions. But I've emailed support at ZA and box with no luck. Each point fingers at the other.

[image: Here is the message from box.net]

I am clueless what to do.  As I said in the post title, I have no problems accessing the site in Chrome. So the sherlock holmes in me says that FF is the culprit, but how to make the changes suggested in the link above? And from a security standpoint, do I want this? Could this "open the dam" to other potentially harmful sites too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some security add-on to Firefox is probably blocking either the access or the javascript on box.net.

You can verify this theory by launching `Mozilla Firefox (Safe Mode)` which doesn't use any add-ons. If Firefox called this way can access box.net, then the problem is indeed caused by an add-on.

If this indeed is the case, then you need to examine your installed add-ons. A possible culprit is always NoScript. You may disable them in groups in order to locate the one that's blocking the access. Then configure this add-on to allow box.net and enable them all back.

Comment: That did it! It was NoScript after all. I neglected to allow the other subdomain and that's the whole problem. Thanks!